# Angular Isolated Scope for multiselect list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently trying to find a nice solution for allowing users a multi-select list. I found a great code-pen that illustrated what I want to use with the ionic framework.

http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/CImqy

But I would like to have multiple select lists and If I add another to the pen

```
<fancy-select
    header-text="Multiple"
    allow-empty='false'
    value="val.multiple2"
    text="countries_text_multiple"
    items="countries"
    multi-select="true"            
    >
</fancy-select>
```

Making sure to bind the value to a different value it still alters the existing one.... is there a way to have the model isolated , I looked over the code and it seems to do that already but I maybe missing something.

Cheers

Comment: The `fancy-select` directive alters the underlying models with `item.checked = true/false`. You can overcome this by passing separate `countries` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code everything is fine. 
use '@'  instead of '=' in your directive for 'text' attribute.

scope: {
                    'items'        : '='
                    'text'         : '@'(please update this(@) in your code ,and add your directive in html page ), 
                    'value'        : '=', 
                    'callback'     : '&'
                },

I think it will helpfull for you.

Comment: Cool nice and simple the @ seemed to help and then also comment from @miensol above is also correct that the lists also should be separated out so they are independant..